# Python: Inputting files in a directory to a list

Tags: python, list, glob

I understand that with the **glob** or **listdir** modules you can get a list of all the files in a directory. However, I need to know how assign the output from glob or listdir to a variable, in list form, like `listdir("/some/file/") = list` and then be able to `print list` and see a list of all files in `/some/file/`. Please help me out here.

Comment: What did you try? Please post the code you tried with the error messages you got.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for

```
filelist = os.listdir("/some/path/")
print filelist
```

If so, consider to work through a Python tutorial :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I guess it is time I actually properly learned python instead of just google different modules and such. :^)